# Correct way to load ListView data source initially

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-state, flutter-future

I have a stateful widget whose state builds a `ListView`. The `ListView` gets its data from an http API. I am using a `Future<void>` method called `getData` to retrieve this data and populate a `List<>` with it before calling `setState`.

My question is where should I call `getData` when this screen first launches? If I call it in `initState()`, I get the following error in the debug console:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_InheritedTheme>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _EventListState.initState() completed.
```

If I wrap the call to `getData` in a delayed `Future`, I do not see the error. Here's my code:

```
class _EventListState extends State<EventList> {

  Future<void> getData() async {
    events = [];
    events = await Network.getUsers(context);
    setState(() {});
  }

  List<Event> events = [];

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData(); // this cause the error
    // Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), getData); // this works
  }

  @override
  build(context) {
    return PlatformScaffold(
      iosContentPadding: true,
      body: ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: events.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(events[index].summary),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Forcing a delay to retrieve the data does not feel right, so is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use FutureBuilder.

```
List<Event> events = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return PlatformScaffold(
            iosContentPadding: true,
            body: ListView.builder(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: events.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(events[index].summary),
            ),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
        } else {
          return Center(child: Text('Please wait its loading...'));
        }
      },
      future: getData(),
    );
  }

  Future<void> getData() async {
    events = [];
    events = await Network.getUsers(context);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Divya. I am now trying to use a RefreshIndicator alongside FutureBuilder and the UI is not updating - will post a separate question.